# what do these time series correlations mean in R?

Tags: r, matrix, time-series, correlation

let say my 2 time series data sets are as below:

```
temp <- matrix(c(12,8,9,11,10,3,7,2,4), byrow = TRUE, ncol = 3)
rownames(temp) <- c("Denver", "LA", "NY")
colnames(temp) <- c("day-1", "day-2", "day-3")
humidity <- matrix(c(70,67,34,45,56,47,68,74,36), byrow = TRUE, ncol = 3)
colnames(humidity)<- c("day-1", "day-2", "day-3")
rownames(humidity)<- c("Denver", "LA", "NY")


> temp
       day-1 day-2 day-3
Denver    12     8     9
LA        11    10     3
NY         7     2     4


> humidity
       day-1 day-2 day-3
Denver    70    67    34
LA        45    56    47
NY        68    74    36



> cor(humidity)
           day-1      day-2      day-3
day-1  1.0000000  0.8924544 -0.9974590
day-2  0.8924544  1.0000000 -0.8580461
day-3 -0.9974590 -0.8580461  1.0000000

> cor(temp)
          day-1     day-2     day-3
day-1 1.0000000 0.9078413 0.5291067
day-2 0.9078413 1.0000000 0.1245339
day-3 0.5291067 0.1245339 1.0000000


> cor(humidity, temp)
           day-1      day-2      day-3
day-1 -0.2584615 -0.6397084  0.6829690
day-2 -0.6664738 -0.9176629  0.2799863
day-3  0.1889822  0.5833240 -0.7332730
```

I m not sure how to interprete this for time series? 
1- which cor show if the variables are corelated?
2- why cities are not ignored?
3- in the third `cor(humidity, temp)` , the main diagonal values are not one in cor matrix. how come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (i,j)th element of the third matrix (`cor(humidity, temp)`) shows the correlation between the ith column of `humidity` and the jth column of `temp`. Illustration:

```r
cor(c(12,11,7),c(70,45,68)) ## day-1 humidities vs day-1 temps (m[1,1])
cor(c(8,10,2), c(70,45,68)) ## day-2 humidities vs day-1 temps (m[2,1])
```

It might be easier to interpret the results if you set

```r
cc <- cor(humidity, temp)
names(dimnames(cc)) <- c("humidity", "temp")
```